# check if my OS release is CentOS or not

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

using `cat/etc/redhat-release`gives me output

**Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)**

Is my OS release CentOS or not?
Secondly, How to check?
And upon searching I came to know that Santiago is codename for this distribution. Then how Santiago & centOS differs? are they related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `/etc/issue` to get additional branding/OS issue on RedHat based operating systems.  This has been buggy in the past, so you can additionally check `rpm -q centos-release` or `/etc/os-release`.

Note that `/etc/issue` is meant to be read by the tty, so check out `man agetty` if you see lines like `\S` or `Kernel \r on an \m` and want to know what that means.

Santiago just is a release name for RHEL 6.2.

Finally, for even more information, check out `lsb_release -a` and you'll see lines for `Distributor ID`, and `Description`.

Comment: on doing rpm -q centos-release my system is giving output-- package centOS release is not installed...so can i conclude that it is not centOS?

Comment: My guess would be it's not CentOs, but check out `lsb_release`.

Comment: output of lsb_release -a has been updated in my question section...now can you tell..how could we infer?

Comment: @Guru you can accept the answer to note that it solved your question.  I noticed you edited the text of your question in response to my answer -- StackOverflow is not designed to interactive in this way and I'm going to revert your changes to make this question helpful to others.

Comment: @Guru it looks like you're on a RedHat install.

Comment: the edit I made was just to tell you the output of lsb_release -a command?
what are doing man?

Comment: @Guru I saw that, but that's not the way the StackOverflow interface is meant to work (answerers aren't notified of edits in the question; comment replies are meant for minor follow-ups) -- I hope you don't find this rude as that's not my intention.  It looks like you're on RedHat based on the output of `/etc/redhat-release` and the fact that `lsb_release` does not mention CentOS.

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)